# Custom Display Names for Child Object's properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm following along the ASP.NET MVC 5 book, but I've ran into an itch that the book doesn't seem to scratch. I have an Album model as so:

```
namespace MvcMusicStore.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public virtual int      AlbumId { get; set; }
        public virtual int      GenreId { get; set; }
        public virtual int      ArtistId { get; set; }

        public virtual string   Title { get; set; }
        public virtual decimal  Price { get; set; }
        public virtual string   AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

        public virtual Genre    Genre { get; set; }
        public virtual Artist   Artist { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To make a long story short, the `Genre` and `Artist` models both have a field called `Name`. When I list these using the `StoreManagerController`, it displays simply as "Name" in each of the headers. I can add a DataAnnotation to `Genre` and `Artist` suchs as `[Display(Name="Artist Name")]`, but I only want it to display as "Artist Name" in this particular instance. I don't want it to be so specific when I am on the "Edit Artist Page."

I understand that I should go about doing this by using a ViewModel, but I am still confused as the view model would still just be pulling in the object, and that object's Display annotations are set in the model itself.

Or better yet, is this something that's best left to the markup?

Comment: until you can add `MetadataType` at the property level, you'll have to handle this in the view.  Depending on how many other entities have an `Artist` you can set the `Display` to `Artist Name` in the `Artist` class and just override it on the "Edit Artist Page"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not if you use view models properly. Many people end up creating view models like:

```
public class FooViewModel
{
    public Foo MyFoo { get; set; }
}
```

That's just a waste of time. Instead, you view models should completely stand in for whatever entity your editing, which means, instead of just referencing the entity, you create properties in your view model for all the properties in your entity that you want to view/edit. Then, in your controller actions, you "map" to and from your entity and view model, which is to say, you just set the properties on one with the values of the appropriate properties on the other.

In your situation then, you would need something like:

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string AlbumArtUrl { get; set; }

    public GenreViewModel Genre { get; set; }
    public ArtistViewModel Artist { get; set; }
}

public class ArtistViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ...
}

public class GenreViewModel
{
    ...
}
```

Then, you can set the display name to be whatever you want on this view model. If you need a different display name in another context, create a separate view model for that.

Also, what's up with all the `virtual`s? The `virtual` keyword merely means that the property/method can be overridden by a subclass. While it technically doesn't hurt anything to just make everything virtual, it's code smell unless you truly intend something to be overridden, or even subclassed in the first place. Traditionally, on entities, the only thing you'll ever add `virtual` to is navigation properties, as this allows Entity Framework to apply its lazy loading logic to your entity. (It literally creates subclasses of your entities dynamically, called "proxies", that add the lazy loading logic to the navigation properties' getter.) If you don't have a navigation property or even if you just don't want lazy loading enabled for that navigation property, then you shouldn't use virtual, unless you really mean to.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure. The book said there was a good reason for it and it'd explain it later on. I'm pretty sure it has to do with EF and migrations though? Also, within your solution, wouldn't it be required that You inherit the original model, or by naming it <ModelName>ViewModel does EF implement that functionality?

Comment: No. The point is to break ties with the entity. Anytime your view is interacting directly with an entity, it's really only a matter of time before you're going to run into issues. The purpose of a view model is to serve a view or views, while the purpose of an entity is solely to represent the structure of a database table. You can't serve both masters without sacrificing something. If your book is telling you it's a good idea to feed your entity directly to a view or worse, use a view model that merely wraps your entity class, it's time to find a new book.

Comment: Passage from the text: "Virtual properties are not required, but they do give EF a hook into your plain C# classes and enable features seuch as an efficient change-tracking mechanism. The EF needs to know when a property value on a model changes, because it might need to issue a SQL UPDATE statement to reconcile those changed with the database." `Galloway, J. et. al., 2014, Professional ASP.NET MVC 5`

Comment: Chris, the book isn't explaining how to do the ViewModels in this context. I'm asking for understanding. Just because I call something an ArtistViewModel, then how do the fields that I apply it get populated by the data from the database? How does it know that it is associated with the Artist object?

Comment: You populate it by mapping the values from your entity onto it. You can do this manually, but there are libraries like AutoMapper that can help you out in this regard. Again, the goal is actually to break that tie to the database entity. Your view shouldn't know or care how the data its working with is persisted, or even if it *is* persisted, and this is actually a source of confusion for many new developers, as once you post back, your entity is no longer an entity, anyways. It's merely a class instance with no ties to any database.

Comment: In regards to the the quoted text, as far as I'm aware, the author is completely incorrect here. EF's change tracking is not dependent on subclassing/overriding. The `virtual` keyword is only necessary for enabling lazy loading on navigation properties. If I'm wrong on this account, I'll be the first to admit it, but I need to see something from Microsoft to the contrary.

Comment: Thanks a ton. That was a very explanation. What made it so confusing to me is when it comes to these "magical" frameworks it's sometimes confusing as to what will happen automatically and what will not. Taking a look at ASP.NET MVC 5's default "AccountViewModels.cs" has helped clear it up as well. Thank you for you time, sir!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do something like this.

```
public class AlbumViewModel
{
    public int AlbumId { get; set; }

    public AlbumGenre Genre { get; set; }
    public AlbumArtist Artist { get; set; }

}

[MetadataType(typeof(AlbumArtistMetadata))]
public class AlbumArtist : Artist {
    private class AlbumArtistMetadata {
        [Display(Name="Artist Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}

[MetadataType(typeof(AlbumGenreMetadata))]
public class AlbumGenre : Genre
{
    private class AlbumGenreMetadata
    {
        [Display(Name = "Genre Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Though I'm not sure I'd inherit from the entities, but instead create models based on the entities.